# Selectively Dump Data with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, yii2

I need to export a table from my database using WHERE. Only result with condition.
I use yii2:

```
        $mysql_file = Yii::getAlias('@app/mysqldump.sql');
        preg_match('#mysql:host=([^;]+);dbname=(.*)#', Yii::$app->components['db']['dsn'], $dbmatch);
        $db = [
            'host' => $dbmatch[1],
            'user' => Yii::$app->components['db']['username'],
            'pass' => Yii::$app->components['db']['password'],
            'base' => $dbmatch[2]
        ];
        
        $command = "mysqldump --user={$db['user']} --password={$db['pass']} --host={$db['host']} {$db['base']} verification --where='program = ".$request->post('course')."' --result-file={$mysql_file} 2>&1";

        exec($command, $output);

        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;

        header('Content-Type: application/sql');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dump-'.$dbmatch[2].'_'.date('YmdHis').'.sql');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($mysql_file)).' GMT', true, 200);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($mysql_file));

        readfile($mysql_file);
```

Problem here:

```
--where='program = ".$request->post('course')."'
```

Result in dump file like this:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `verification`

--
-- WHERE:  program = a1n2
```

Without WHERE working fine.

Comment: that is tricky your variable has to be in quotes, but you used up already both variants

Comment: Like this? --where="program = 'myvalue'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote $request->post('course')  with `\"`

Which will escape tzhe double quote

like

```
$command = "mysqldump --user={$db['user']} --password={$db['pass']} --host={$db['host']} {$db['base']} verification --where='program = \"".$request->post('course')."\"' --result-file={$mysql_file} 2>&1";
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I completely forgot about \ "

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split up the command in this manner? I am not a yii developer but is what i would do in java/php or anything else

```
'mysqldump --user='.{$db['user']}.' --password='.{$db['pass']}.' --host='.{$db['host']}.' '.{$db['base']}.' verification --where=program = "'.$request->post('course').'".....
```